# How to Convert DataTable Column values from One Unit to another in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable, unit-conversion

I have a `DataTable` with some Column values filled with. **I want to Convert the Column values from one unit to another.**

```
DataTable Columns(Name,Height,Width)
```

Eg:Inch to Meter, Meter to Centimeter etc.

```
Id  UnitName
1   Inches
2   Millimeters
3   Fractions
4   Decimal
5   Feet
6   Centimeters
7   Meters

private string Convert(string strToConvert, int from, int to)
        {
            //some code here
            return strToConvert;
        }
```

Comment: What are you looking for here ? The code to do it ? Iterate over your rows and columns and call row.SetValue() to set a new value.

Comment: You could let each unit have a factor to a standard unit. For example I think meter is the standard length unit, so `meter = 1`, and therefore `centimeter = 0.01`, `millimeter = 0.001` and so on. Then, when you have a value in one unit, multiply it by that units factor and divide it by the factor of the desired unit. `5cm * 0.01 = 0.05; 0.05 / 0.001 = 50mm`.

Comment: confused!whether to do using Linq or by just looping through each row? Any idea using Linq?

Comment: Why is your return type a string? shouldn't it by a double? same question for the first argument

Comment: Hello @asafrob, the column  may contain values such as 10cm,10,10 mm etc. and thus the source format & value to convert to are stored in database and accordingly convert those values hence its String.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to keep the conversion data in some sort of container, for example to keep a matrix of values where each row will use for from unit and each column will for to unit (so if x==y the value will be 1 since converting from any unit to the same unit is multiplying it by one)

After you have the matrix your code will look like:

```
double value_to_convert = Double.Parse(strToConvert);
return (value_to_convert* mat[from][to]).ToString();
```